# ActiveSheet.Paste does not work in workbook event, but works in module

Tags: vba, excel

The `ActiveSheet.Paste` code after a workbook is added works when I place it in a `Module` but if I placed it inside the `Workbook AfterSave Event` it returns an error. When I tried `Debug.Print(Application.ActiveSheet.Name) it prints`Sheet1`and`Debug.Print(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Name) as `Book13` so it should be correct. I also tried placing `Range("A1").Select` but it does not paste still.

[image]

```
Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)

'This section just counts total number of rows for worksheets    
Dim Total_rows_Entries As Long
Dim Total_rows_Payees As Long
Dim Total_rows_Accounts As Long

Workbooks("ONLINE-CASH VOUCHER.xlsm").Activate

With Worksheets("Entries").ListObjects("Entries").ListColumns(3).Range
Total_rows_Entries = .Find(What:="*", _
    After:=.Cells(1), _
    Lookat:=xlPart, _
    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
    MatchCase:=False).Row
End With

With Worksheets("List of Payees").ListObjects("ListofPayees").ListColumns(1).Range
Total_rows_Payees = .Find(What:="*", _
    After:=.Cells(1), _
    Lookat:=xlPart, _
    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
    MatchCase:=False).Row
End With

With Worksheets("List of Accounts").ListObjects("ListofAccounts").ListColumns(1).Range
Total_rows_Accounts = .Find(What:="*", _
    After:=.Cells(1), _
    Lookat:=xlPart, _
    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
    MatchCase:=False).Row
End With

'Problem is in this section    
Dim vArr As String
Dim lastColumn As Long
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet
Dim copy_Path As String
Dim open_wb As Boolean

copy_Path = "C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\"
For Each WS In Workbooks("ONLINE-CASH VOUCHER.xlsm").Worksheets
    If WS.Name = "Entries" Or WS.Name = "List of Accounts" Or WS.Name = "List of Payees" Then
        lastColumn = Worksheets(WS.Name).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        vArr = Split(Cells(1, lastColumn).Address(True, False), "$")(0)
        Worksheets(WS.Name).Range("A1:" & vArr & Total_rows_Entries).Copy
        Set wb = Workbooks.Add
        'Error is this ActiveSheet.Paste
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        open_wb = IsWorkBookOpen(copy_Path & WS.Name & ".xlsx")
        If open_wb = True Then
            Workbooks(WS.Name & ".xlsx").Close
        End If
        wb.SaveAs copy_Path & WS.Name & ".xlsx"
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Is this within the ONLINE-CASH VOUCHER.xlsm workbook or are you activating an external workbook?

Comment: Yes this is the ONLINE-CASH  VOUCHER.xlsm workbook's aftersave event. Although the ActiveSheet.Paste pastes in a new workbook file after `Set wb=Workbooks.Add`. If I copy and paste the exact code into a `sub test()` it will work with no problems.

Comment: Actually I just made a sub procedure and then I just put a `Call Procedure` in the aftersave event and it works. Just can't understand why it won't work in the event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these revisions.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)

    'This section just counts total number of rows for worksheets
    Dim Total_rows_Entries As Long
    Dim Total_rows_Payees As Long
    Dim Total_rows_Accounts As Long

    'With Workbooks("ONLINE-CASH VOUCHER.xlsm")
    With ThisWorkbook

        With .Worksheets("Entries").ListObjects("Entries").ListColumns(3).Range
            Total_rows_Entries = .Find(What:="*", _
                After:=.Cells(1), _
                Lookat:=xlPart, _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                MatchCase:=False).Row
        End With

        With .Worksheets("List of Payees").ListObjects("ListofPayees").ListColumns(1).Range
            Total_rows_Payees = .Find(What:="*", _
                After:=.Cells(1), _
                Lookat:=xlPart, _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                MatchCase:=False).Row
        End With

        With .Worksheets("List of Accounts").ListObjects("ListofAccounts").ListColumns(1).Range
            Total_rows_Accounts = .Find(What:="*", _
                After:=.Cells(1), _
                Lookat:=xlPart, _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                MatchCase:=False).Row
        End With

        Dim copy_Path As String
        Dim lastColumn As Long, total_Rows As Long
        Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
        Dim open_wb As Boolean

        copy_Path = "C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\"

        For Each ws In .Worksheets
            With ws
                Select Case .Name
                    Case "Entries"
                        total_Rows = Total_rows_Entries
                    Case "List of Accounts"
                        total_Rows = Total_rows_Accounts
                    Case "List of Payees"
                        total_Rows = Total_rows_Payees
                End Select
                Select Case .Name
                    Case "Entries", "List of Accounts", "List of Payees"
                        On Error Resume Next
                        Workbooks(ws.Name & ".xlsx").Close savechanges:=False
                        Set wb = Workbooks.Add
                        On Error GoTo 0

                        lastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                        .Range(.Cells(1, "A"), .Cells(total_Rows, lastColumn)).Copy _
                            Destination:=wb.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1)
                        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                        wb.SaveAs Filename:=copy_Path & ws.Name, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
                        wb.Close savechanges:=False
                        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                End Select
            End With
        Next

    End With

End Sub
```